# How many different subsets of a $10$-element set are there where the subsets have at LEAST $8$ elements?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

How many different subsets of a $10$-element set are there where the subsets have at LEAST $8$ elements?

My answer:

There are $\binom{10}{7}$ subsets with $7$ elements or less, so $2^{10}-\binom{10}{7}$. IS this right?

Comment: $\binom{10}{7}$ is the number of subsets with ``exactly'' seven elements. So with your approach you should have $2^{10}-\sum_{i=0}^{7}\binom{10}{i}$.

Comment: No, because ${10 \choose 7}$ is the number of subsets with *EXACTLY* $7$ elements.  So you need $2^{10} - {10 \choose 7} - {10 \choose 6} - .....{10 \choose 1} - {10 \choose 0}$.  It would actuall be easier to calculate ${10 \choose 8} + {10 \choose 9}+ {10 \choose 10}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of $8$-element subsets is $10\choose8$, and the number of $9$-element subsets is $10\choose9$, and the number of $10$-element subsets is $10\choose10$.

So the required ans is $10\choose8$+$10\choose9$+$10\choose10$$=5\times9+10+1=56$

Comment: OR $$2^{10}-\binom{10}{7}-\binom{10}{6}-\binom{10}{5}-\binom{10}{4}-\binom{10}{3}-\binom{10}{2}-\binom{10}{1}-\binom{10}{0}$$?

Comment: yep......but its lengthy

Answer (score 1):

No; there are ${10\choose 7}$ subsets of *exactly* $7$ elements. There are ${10\choose 8}$ subsets with $8$ elements, ${10\choose 9}$ with nine elements, and ${10\choose 10}$ with $10$ elements. Therefore, there are ${10\choose 8}+{10\choose 9}+{10\choose 10}$ subsets with at least $8$ elements.